# UIImagePickerController and Landscape orientation

Tags: objective-c

I have an UIImagePicker to click a picture and pick an image from photo gallery. But my Application has to support only landscape orientation. The photo gallery opens in portrait mode only via ImagePicker. I tried integrating the current code with ALAssets, but i have no idea about the AlAssets library. I want to use the image Picker and make it call the ALAssets in the startMediaBrowserFromViewController: method. Below is the method definition. Please provide me a solution.

```
//pick an image from photo gallery  

- (BOOL) startMediaBrowserFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller
                               usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                                               UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate {


    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
          UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum] == NO)
        || (delegate == nil)
        || (controller == nil))
        return NO;
    UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    mediaUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    //provides access to photo albums in the device.
    mediaUI.mediaTypes=[[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage,nil]autorelease];
    // Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures.
    mediaUI.allowsEditing = NO;   
    mediaUI.delegate = delegate;
    [controller presentModalViewController: mediaUI animated: YES];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Could you found a solution? I have the same situation and try to found the manner. I saw this app "Story Creator" in his iphone version and do the trick, but i can't found it yet.

Answer (score 0):

`UIImagePickerController` supports only `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` orientation, so it doesn't matter if it is presented from landscape viewcontroller, it will be shown int portrait orientation, not even in `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown`

Answer (score 0):

I use `ELCImagePickerController` to pick images. For me it at has many advantages compared to the "normal" `UIImagePickerController`:

- you can pick multiple Images
- easily support of landscape mode
- easy to customize
- ...

I think on default it does not support landscape orientation, but I got this working pretty easy. Leave a comment if you need help there.

Check it on [Gituhub](https://github.com/elc/ELCImagePickerController)